# Getting cluster information from Apache Mesos

Tags: api

I am recently started working with [Apache Mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/) and got the very basic set up running. It provides a very informative WebUI that provides information related to currently active/deactivated slaves, running tasks, CPU etc.

Apology if this sound stupid but what I was looking for if there is any API available to access these information so that I can populated my custom object model and use them in my own application. The information available on Mesos UI seems relevant but I couldn't find any way to access them.

Any advice on the same?

Comment: This is a question about a feature of Apache Mesos right? As such, it would probably be more on-topic at http://serverfault.com Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

all stats returned from the Mesos in json format is exposed using the URL : 
`http://localhost:5050/metrics/snapshot`  where localhost should be replaced with the actual ip of the server hosting mesos master.

The metrics looks like

```
    {"master/cpus_percent":0,"master/cpus_total":0,"master/cpus_used":0,"master/disk_percent":0, ......}
```